# How can I control my user's post?

Tags: php, mysql

Please look at the image:
[image]

This is a simple forum page. Anyone can open as well as publish a new topic, if he/she just got registered. But now I want to control my users. I want if anybody open a new topic, it won't be published directly in my website. First it has to come to admin to be approved. But I can't find any clue to do it. Just share with me the concept, I will do it myself.

Comment: Where should I learn this thing? I have no idea.

Comment: How could we possibly know how to operate your forum software without even knowing what forum software you are using?!

Comment: I am not using any software. I just take input by a simple html form, then store it in mysql database. Then just show them by calling from database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply add an `approved` flag in the database which is set to `0` by default and once approved is set to `1`. Only approved topics are listed (`WHERE approved = 1`) and editable. And unapproved topics are listed int the admin menu which can either accept them or not (editing that flag in the database).

Comment: That's the solution what I wanted. Thanks.